# Python regex on text file

Tags: python, xml, regex

Hi guys I have question about regex, I need a litle help about something. My code looks like:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re

WEEKDAYS = ["nedjelja", "utorak", "četvrtak", "ponedjeljak", "subota", "srijeda", "petak"]:

with open('natio_geo_channel.xml', 'r') as input_file, \
        open('nat.xml', 'w') as output_file:
    for line in input_file:
        for x in WEEKDAYS
            line = line.replace("<para>" + x, "<date>")
        line = re.sub(r"<para>\d{0}", "<start>", line)
        line = re.sub(r"<start>\d{2}\.\d{2}\s/\s/", "</start>", line)
        output_file.write(line)
```

My file looks like :

```
<para>nedjelja1. rujna 2013.</para>
    <para>06.00        na hrvatskom Zona gradnje: Izgradnja zelenog Pekinga</para>
    <para>Kineske nevolje sa zagađenjem problem su s globalnim posljedicama. Pratite ekipu zelenih inženjera koji grade energetski učinkoviti Peking.</para>
```

What I've did, I replaced first  with  and in it remove nedjelja thats ok.
But how can I do this:

```
<start>06:00<start><title>Zona gradnje</title><sub>Izgradnja zelenog Pekinga</sub>
```

from this `<para>06.00        na hrvatskom Zona gradnje: Izgradnja zelenog Pekinga</para>`

Can you give me some advice or thinking way?

Comment: So how exactly are the code snippet and 1 snippet of XML related to your question?

Comment: Use an XML parser, e.g. the built-in ElementTree, and manipulate the DOM. Don't use regex to parse XML.

Comment: Please dont comment if you dont know what I'm doing. It's not xml, it was .doc(word) doc, i dont know any convertor who can convert .doc to csv, or xls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
def main():    
    line = r'<para>06.00        na hrvatskom Zona gradnje: Izgradnja zelenog Pekinga</para>'        
    if re.search(r'^(<para>)\d{2}.\d{2}', line):
        line_time = re.findall(r'\d{2}.\d{2}',line)[0]       
        line_title = line[line.find(re.findall(r'[A-Z]',line)[0]):line.find(':')]        
        line_sub = line[line.find(':')+1:line.find(r'</')].strip()

        print '<start>'+line_time+'</start><title>'+line_title+'</title><sub>'+line_sub+'</sub>'
```

Let me know if this is what you needed.

**OUTPUT**

```
<start>06.00</start><title>Zona gradnje</title><sub>Izgradnja zelenog Pekinga</sub>
```

Use this for reading line from files:

```
 with open(r'D:\Trading\PythonScholar\input\input.tx','r') as file: 
        for line in file:            
            if re.search(r'^(<para>)\d{2}.\d{2}', line.strip()): 
                line_time = re.findall(r'\d{2}.\d{2}',line)[0] 
                line_title = line[line.find(re.findall(r'[A-Z]',line)[0]):line.find(':')] 
                line_sub = line[line.find(':')+1:line.find(r'</')].strip() 
                print '<start>'+line_time+'</start><title>'+line_title+'</title><sub>'+line_sub+'</sub>'
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thx man ill try, the main problem this was first .doc(word), I converted that to xml coz, its fast for regex. I know for ETtree but it wont help me now, only xls-t would help. Ill try with that. Thx a lot!

Comment: I want to say thx for helping me out! That code above worked!

Comment: You are welcome my friend... :)

Comment: Hey Vivek how can this work with file, like open file and read lines like i posted from up. Can you help me out?

Comment: sure. with open(r'<file_location>','r') as file: use this

Comment: with open(r'natio_geo_channel.xml','r') as file:
 for line in file:
  if re.search(r'^(<para>)\d{2}.\d{2}', line):
       line_time = re.findall(r'\d{2}.\d{2}',line)[0]       
       line_title = line[line.find(re.findall(r'[A-Z]',line)[0]):line.find(':')]        
       line_sub = line[line.find(':')+1:line.find(r'</')].strip()
       print '<start>'+line_time+'</start><title>'+line_title+'</title><sub>'+line_sub+'</sub

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38470/discussion-between-car-and-vivek)

Answer (score 1):

To convert this:

```
<para>06.00        na hrvatskom Zona gradnje: Izgradnja zelenog Pekinga</para>
```

To this:

```
<start>06:00<start><title>Zona gradnje</title><sub>Izgradnja zelenog Pekinga</sub>
```

Do this:

```
str = re.sub(".*?>(\S+)(?:\s+\S+){2}\s+(.*?):\s*(.*)<.*", 
    "<start>\1<start><title>\2</title><sub>\3</sub>", str)
```

Comment: Always love the use of RE. +1 from me @Bohemian , thanks for this.